# How to take two different string array elements as input to one 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to take array elements of two sting arrays as input to one 2D array , in order to illustrate further .. I want something that looks like below

```
String[] a = a1,a2,a3,...
String[] b = b1, b2, b3,...
String[i][j] = [i loop all elements from array a[]][j loop all from elements array b[]]
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Please take some more efforts to describe what exactly you are trying to do. At least you should show what should be the outcome of the program you intend to write.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize new 2d array with `a` and `b`

```
String[] a = {"a0", "a1", "a2"};
String[] b = {"b0", "b1", "b2"};

String[][] c = {a, b};
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a matrix n by m where n and m are the lengths of the given arrays. You don't really say what you want to be in the matrix but if you were concatenating the string elements:

`String[] a = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
 String[] b = {"11", "22", "33"};`

```
    String[][] retval = Arrays.stream(a)
            .map(s -> Arrays.stream(b).map(x -> s + x)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0][]);

    System.out.println(retval[1][2]);
```

`// prints bb33`

would do it.